# How to Pass separate file from view in Handlebar JS?

Tags: javascript, layout, handlebars.js

I facing issue while using handlebar.JS my issue is pretty simple but i can't get the solution :)

**Issue:**How I can pass the JS or CSS file in footer or header  partial in Handlebar.JS

***More Detail of My Existing Issue***

In footer I have change .js file for each page like for **home page** i have 6 .js files and in **user page** I have 8 .js file also its change from **home page** so in this case how can i add these .js file in my footer partial

I have one layout in Handlebar.JS

```
<body>
{{>header}}
{{body}}
{{>footer}}
</body>
```

I create header and footer partials and all .js files in footer now issue is I need to add one specific file from **{{body}}** view that will render in my **{{>footer}}** partial.

Is it possible if yes then how can i archive my objective?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters there, something like this:

```
{{ > footer paramName='something.js' }}

// then your footer partial has it:
{{ paramName }}
```

And you can render it as a script tag or script src or what you need.

Comment: sorry actually its not properly working because I add this in my {{body}} it render two footers and its not good.